# Angular 2 - form without prompt

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I have a form for searching items in table

```
<div class="container">
    <h4>Search product</h4>
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                <label for="productName">Product name:</label>
                <input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" type="text" class="form-control search-box">
                <div>
                    <div *ngFor="let product of products | async" (click)="gotoDetail(product)" class="search-result">
                        {{ product.name }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And when I click the input then slides out the history of entered data and lower divs which I want to show.

How to hide the history of entered phrases?

I need only div with found products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) in your input field.

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Answer (score 3):

Turn off [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Try to add `autocomplete="off"` attribute to your input